# How to specify automatic java heap dump in binary format

Tags: java, heap-dump

when using -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError can we specify out format as binary?

Answer (score 0):

The heap dump is in HPROF binary format (binary format) by default, and so it can be analyzed using any tools that can import this format.

You can get whole details here

https://technicalsand.com/how-to-take-heap-dumps-8-different-options/